# How to correct an old bathroom ceiling vent fan duct (or lack thereof) in an old 2 story house

Tags: bathroom, ducts, exhaust-fan

I'm fixing up an old home, built in 1930s, renovated in 1980s that has a terrifying fire hazard of a bathroom light/vent fan/heater in the downstairs hall bathroom. When this old unit was removed, not only was it not vented to the outside, there was no duct or anything attached. It was apparently just venting straight into the space between the floors.

I'm trying to fix it properly and vent it to the outside and luckily, there is an opening approximately 15 feet away diagonally through the crawlspace between the 2 floors to an outside utility closet where the HVAC/furnace is that seems like the best option. I realize it's a slightly long run but since it's a straight shot, I believe it will work based on the specs of the fan and if use rigid duct (or maybe semi-rigid).

The challenge is getting the duct between these 2 openings. The outside opening is almost behind the furnace so can't get ladder close enough in the small space to get all the way up next to it (to see parallel across the crawlspace). On the inside, without tearing out more drywall/ceiling, due to the framing/ductwork in the bathroom, I can only get my head  a few inches through the opening in the bathroom ceiling, but not high enough to see over framing.

I have measured and tried to line up and tried to find a way to run something semi-rigid (like a tape measure) across the space to line it up so I could pull the new duct across but without being able to see across the space, I'm trying to push across it blindly and (obviously) running into things like pipe or the bigger HVAC ducts.

Does anyone have an idea for a better way to get this done? It seems like there should be an easier way to do this without making a huge hole in the ceiling but maybe I'm just making it harder than it should be...thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Try pushing from the outside, you will have to be there to make the hole and add the vent.

Comment: Pushing something sharp like a duct, where you cannot see can be bad if it is pushed against electric cables.  Usually fixing a bigger hole is as easy as a small hole and maybe make the work easier and faster.

Comment: You did a reasonable job of describing the situation, but, as the old saying goes, a picture is worth 1000 words. Some pictures and a diagram (even if not to scale, but with dimensions drawn on) will help immensely. Your idea sounds good (I think), but others may even come up with a better idea or options that that didn't occur to you, but will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you all! I do think enlarging the opening on the inside so I can see across will be the easiest option--in the time I've spent thinking about it, I probably could have already done it and fixed the drywall! I appreciate the suggestions :)